# CoreData: How to display fetched data to UIcollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionviewcell, nsfetchrequest

currently I have this **loadCharacters** function

```
    var characterArray = [Character]()

    func loadCharacters(with request: NSFetchRequest<Character> = Character.fetchRequest()) {
        
        do {
            characterArray = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("error loading data")
        }        
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

My question is: How can I pass the fetched Data from there to my subclass **CharacterCollectionViewCell** and later on use this cell for my

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "characterCell",
 for: indexPath) as! CharacterCollectionViewCell { 
    ... 
}
```

any suggestion or any better way to make it works are really appreciated!!

Comment: You want to pass one index of your charachterArray to cell subclass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to get the `characterArray` element corresponding to the `indexPath.item` and use it to pass it into the cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "characterCell",
 for: indexPath) as! CharacterCollectionViewCell { 
        cell.someLabel.text = characterArray[indexPath.item]
        //...
        return cell
}
```

If you have too much data to be passed on it's better to create a model and use it's instance to pass data on to the cell. So, for that firstly create a model.

```
struct CharacterCellModel { // all properties... }
```

Then in your `UIViewController` sub-class.

```
var characterCellModels = [CharacterCellModel]() // append this model
```

And finally in `cellForItemAt`:

```
cell.characterCellModel = characterCellModels[indexPath.item]
```

Comment: the reason I'm using collectionViewCell because I also have others stuffs to do with the cell like images, imageCatching... And if I combine everything, it will be a big mess

Comment: Create a model for all the data you need to pass and use it to pass the data to the cell. Check the update, I've added a small example.

Comment: awesome! I will give it a try!! Thank you so much